# View Model class with multiple similar properties

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a view model class that I want to use to provide a visibility property of multiple columns in a data grid to bind to.  Here is a snippet of what I have.

```
class ViewVM
{
  private bool[] columnVisible;

  public ViewVM ()
  {
    columnVisible = new bool[12];
  }

  private void BuildData(int BuildPeriod)
  {
    //Do stuff
    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
    {
      if (i <= BuildPeriod) columnVisible[i] = true;
      else columnVisible[i] = false;
    }
  }

  public bool Column1Visible { get { return columnVisible[1]; } }
  public bool Column2Visible { get { return columnVisible[2]; } }
  public bool Column3Visible { get { return columnVisible[3]; } }
  //etc
}
```

My problem is I don't want to have a property to bind to for every column.  I would rather have something like the following, but C# doesn't support parameters in properties.  Does anyone have a suggestion how I can do something similar to the following?

```
public bool ColumnVisible [int Column] 
{ 
  get { return columnVisible[Column]; } 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a converter. I.e. if you want columns to be invisible if they are null then you could write a nulltovisibilityconverter and bind to the columns value

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using the Grid class? WPF is awesome at giving your the ability to extend a base control and extend its functionality.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'd have a model for my column values extending from a base class that had a property that indicated whether or not the column was important, or whatever indicates users don't care about the value of the column.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to compose your grid out of custom controls which have their own view models and binding set up. The grid would most likely be made up of several column controls, each with the property you're looking for.